# Cereal Mashing for Adjuncts

Tags: mash, adjuncts, techniques, conversion

What is the step-by-step process for cereal mashing adjuncts?
Please include temps and grain to volume ratios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this author advocates just buying flaked grain, he has a good description of the process:

http://hopwild.com/2009/02/18/cereal-mashing-bother/

You can also check this link for photos:

http://www.ingermann.com/cerealmash.html